# How do I install Popcorn Time from the new Yify Github?

Tags: software-installation

How can I install [Popcorn Time](https://github.com/Yify/popcorn-ap) in Ubuntu?

The old Popcorn Time is no more, the new Popcorn Time is being maintained by yify.

Comment: Man read the installation instructions at least https://github.com/Yify/popcorn-app#building

Comment: @seth please put my question back. the old popcorn time has been closed down, the new popcorn time is being maintained by yify torrents at that github.

Answer (score -1):

To build and install Popcorn Time in Ubuntu using [THIS script](https://raw.github.com/hotice/webupd8/master/popcorn-build). Download and run the script (which will build and install Popcorn Time in Ubuntu) using the following commands:

```
  wget https://raw.github.com/hotice/webupd8/master/popcorn-build
  chmod +x popcorn-build
 ./popcorn-build
```

[Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-popcorn-time-from-source.html)

Comment: @webupd8 Isn't this the one that was taken down? The link I posted was to the one that's not being taken care of by yify.

Comment: No the actual app link is taken down... and i have install it from it ...it download all dependencies and then download app from s3 amazon